# Display Interactive Report for different roles sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

I'm stuck on something, and need some hep with a SQL query. I've created an interactive report with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM FORM f
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANAGER m ON m.MID = f.MID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS u ON u.ID = m.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN MANAGER m2 ON m2.MID = f.MANID
LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS u2 ON u2.ID = c.ID
WHERE lower(u.username) = lower(:session_user_name) 
   OR lower(u2.username) = lower(:session_user_name);
```

The logged in user can have different roles in the form. Depending on the role the id of the manager will be set in different columns of the table.

However, all reports for which the user has been entered,regardless of the role in the form, should still be displayed.

With this query, however, I only see one line for which the has been entered as a Manager.

I don't know much about SQL and don't quite understand what the problem is, can someone help here?

---

Tried with union :

```
select *

FROM FORM f
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MANAGER m ON m.MID = f.MID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS u ON u.ID = m.ID
where lower(u.username)=lower(:session_user_name) 

    union

select *

FROM FORM f2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MANAGER m2 ON m2.MID = f2.MANID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS u2 ON u2.ID = m2.ID
where lower(u2.username)=lower(:session_user_name)
```

---

Table form:

```
create table form (FORMID, COLUMN1 varchar2(50), MID NUMBER,MANID NUMBER);
```

MID and MANID are foreign keys to the table MANAGER

```
create table manager (MID number, COLUMN1 varchar2(30));
```

Example:
Here is a table with some sample data:
[image: form table]

In the interactive report the manager with the id 15, should see both entries like this
[image: Interactive report]

But now he only gets to see one row, the upper row.

Comment: Here is a prompt - use Union SQL

Comment: I already tried this but does not work either:/

Comment: It would be curious to see your code try

Comment: I edited the question as i have misrepresented the facts of the case, I apologize for that

Comment: It would be very helpful to edit the question to include a reproducible test case.  Table definitions, sample data, expected output, actual output, etc.  If you go to dbfiddle.uk or livesql.oracle.com and set up the scenario, that is even better and is much more likely to get you a quick answer.

Comment: Did you setup the "Page Items to Submit"?

Comment: I have no page item to submit

Comment: I edited the question and have added an example, I hope it is now a little more understandable